# Insert hex value in the middle of a string python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, hex

I want to create 5 hex bytes length  string that is gonna be send through a socket. I want that send 255 packets changing the third byte incremntally. How can I do that?
Something like this code:

```
i=0    
while True:
        a="\x3f\x4f"+hex(i)+"\x0D\x0A"
        socket.send(a)
        i=i+1
```

The problem is that this code is introducing 0x0 (30 78 30) instead of 00 in the first loop for example.

Thank you

Comment: As a side note, you might want to look at `bytearray`. It's sort of a hybrid between a `str` and a `list` of small integers. For example, you can construct it as `bytearray('\x3f\x4f\x00\x0d\x0a')` or as `bytearray([0x3f, 0x4f, 0x00, 0x0d, 0x0a])`, then do `a[2] = i` without having to convert, and also do `socket.send(a)` without having to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're a bit confused here.

`\x3f` is a single character (the same character as `?`).

If `i` is, say, 63 (hex 3F), you don't want to add the separate characters `\\`, `x`, `3`, and `f` to the string, you want to add the single character `\x3f`. Likewise, if it's 0 (hex 00), you don't want to add the separate characters `\\`, `x`, `0` to the string, you want to add the single character `\x0`.

---

That's exactly what the [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) function is for:

> Return a string of one character whose ASCII code is the integer *i*. For example, `chr(97)` returns the string `'a'`…

---

By contrast, the function [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) will:

> [c]onvert an integer number (of any size) to a lowercase hexadecimal string prefixed with “0x”…

So, `hex(97)` returns the four character string `'0x61'`.

Comment: Works great! I was in the wrong direction. Thank you.